# How to show QWidget created from a QQuickView in frameless dialog with transparent background

Tags: qt, transparency, qml

I have a `QWidget` created with `QWidget::createWindowContainer` from a `QQuickView`:

```
QQuickView view;
view.setSource(QUrl("./Test.qml"));

QWidget *container = QWidget::createWindowContainer(&view);
```

The Qml is very simple:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
Rectangle {
    width: 50
    height: 50
    color: "blue"
    radius: 5
}
```

I need a translucent frameless container to show the rectangle. Trying to show the widget in a QDialog:

```
QDialog dialog;
QHBoxLayout layout;

dialog.setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
dialog.setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
layout.addWidget(container);
dialog.setLayout(&layout);
dialog.show();
```

i get nothing because it seems that transparency was propagated also to `container` object. If i try to add to `layout` instead of `container` widget, for example, a `QPushButton`, all works fine and only the button is showed. I need the same result with my QML widget. Where could be the problem? I'm using Qt 5.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt it could be done for a QQuickView embedded in a QWidget. But you can have a transparent QQuickView like:

```
QQuickView view;

view.setSurfaceType(QSurface::OpenGLSurface);

QSurfaceFormat format;
format.setAlphaBufferSize(8);
format.setRenderableType(QSurfaceFormat::OpenGL);

view.setFormat(format);
view.setColor(QColor(Qt::transparent));
view.setClearBeforeRendering(true);

view.setFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);

view.setSource(QStringLiteral("./Test.qml"));

view.show();
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But do you think i could avoid OpenGL?